# SphinxSearch: Cannot get result from (remote) agent

Tags: search, full-text-search, search-engine, sphinx, fulltext-index

I build 2 searchd instance on different server(namely A and B) and build a distributed index on A. However, when I query A from client, I only got result from A's index. My problem is I cannot get result from B' index, I am pretty sure I configure correct.

I tried:
* replace hostname with IP adresses
* I am pretty sure that I have not get result from B's index

A's sphinx.conf

```
index distributed_index
{
    type = distributed
    local = A_index
    agent = 192.168.13.189:9312:B_index
    agent_connect_timeout = 1000
    agent_query_timeout = 3000
}
```

client query code(python)

```py
import sphinxapi
sphinx_host = 'A'
sphinx_port = 9312
SphinxClient = sphinxapi.SphinxClient()
SphinxClient.SetServer(sphinx_host,sphinx_port)
SphinxClient.SetMatchMode(sphinxapi.SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED)
res = SphinxClient.Query("")
```

when I `indexer --all --rotate`, got a WARNING:skipping non-plain index 'distributed_index'

I expect results from both from A and B when I query from client.

Comment: Have you tried connecting **direct** to B and see if can run the query on its own? To Check if B is itself working. narrow down if issue is with B or with A :)

Comment: Yes, I did. I can get the result from B's index when I connect B directly. I am realy confused...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I got it guys, I got it!**

The problem is not on the server(A&B), I configured them correctly. It is becacuse I am not familiar with the API.`Query()` API need to specify the **key words** as well as the **queried index**.

`res = SphinxClient.Query("","distributed_index_name")` gives me the correct result!

**If you encounter similar problems, be free to ask, I am happy to help.**

Comment: Ah I see, checking the documentation *Default value for $index is `*` that means to query all local indexes.* - also never noticed it explicitly says **local** indexes, so wouldn't of included the distributed index, only queried `A_index` *directly*. To search a distributed index would have to name it! (also avoids searching, A_index twice ;P)